# Get the access token in an Azure integrated ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

We have the following requirements

1. Create an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC web application
2. Add application registration
3. Integrate Azure authentication for login and logout
4. Get the access token to call other APIs

We have done 1 and 2 they are very straight forward.

We need guidance on how to get the access token,

1. Can we get the access token during the login process itself?
2. If not is there are any oob way of getting the access token after the login process. Thought it would be simple enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get a token, you need to authenticate the user with a known account in an Azure Active Directory. Look at app registrations and using single sign-on. The user will be redirected to a login page that will authenticate the user and send back the token.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-application-management

Comment: hi, thanks we are able to get the authcode but what we need is the accesstoken.

Comment: use microsoft graph. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user

Comment: went through the app, just to get the token they added so much amount of code (Microsoft.Identity.Web project), very surprised that MS did not provide a library for getting the token, my requirement code is 5 lines compared to what the sample does to get the token.